# Error property is not defined when passing an anon function (how to curry)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, currying

I think this technique is called currying.

**Problem:**

https://repl.it/E4iG

```
ReferenceError: type is not defined
    at hasType:14:27
    at allApprovalTypes.map:18:26
    at eval:17:21
    at eval
```

**Question:**
How do I use `hasType` so in the end I can replace the un-named anon function to `approvals.find(hasType)`?

```
   var approvals = [
      {type: 'media'},
      {type: 'scope'},
    ]

    var allApprovalTypes = [
      'media',
      'scope',
      'finance',
      'compliance',
    ];

   var hasType = (el) => {
       return el.type === type;
   }

   allApprovalTypes.map((type) => {
        return approvals.find((el)=> el.type === type) || {type: type} // this works.
   });

   allApprovalTypes.map((type) => {
      return approvals.find(hasType) || {type: type} // this wont work.        
   });
```

Comment: how your `hasType` function know the `type` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hasType is referencing a "type" variable that doesn't exist in its scope. You'll need to inline that function for it to pick up type (or wrap it in a closure, but that's pretty much the same thing)

```
allApprovalTypes.map((type) => {
  return approvals.find((el) => {
       return el.type === type;
   }) || {type: type}
});


   // closure
   var hasType = (type) => (el) => {
       return el.type === type;
   }
```

P.S. - unrelated, but in ES6, "{type: type}" can be shortened to "{ type }"

Comment: How would I wrap it in a closure to make hasType work? This closure is what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm just a bit lost syntax wise.

Comment: Change hasType to a function that accepts "type", but returns your original version of the hasType function. Then, pass hasType(type) in your .find(...):

var hasType = (type) => {
 return (el) => {
     return el.type === type;
 };
};

...

allApprovalTypes.map(type => {
  return approvals.find(hasType(type)) || { type };
});

Comment: ayeee thats what I was looking for.  This technique is called currying right?

Comment: "currying" was a new term for me, but after reading on it, I would say "yes", this particular example could be considered currying

Answer (score 0):

You can by using `.bind()`. You can pass `type` (extra parameters) to callbacks.

```js
var approvals = [
      {type: 'media'},
      {type: 'scope'},
    ]

    var allApprovalTypes = [
      'media',
      'scope',
      'finance',
      'compliance',
    ];

   var hasType = (el, type) => {
       return el.type === type;
   }

   console.log(allApprovalTypes.map((type) => {
        return approvals.find(hasType.bind(null, type)) || {type: type} // this works.
   }));

   

   //without bind();
   console.log(allApprovalTypes.map((type) => {
        return approvals.find((el) => return hasType(el, type)) || {type: type} // this works.
   }));
```

Comment: Answer below says wrap in a closure.  Any ideas on how to achieve this w/o using bind?

Comment: without binding means call the `hasType()` in your `anonymous function` (fat arrow function) . I updated this

Comment: I was looking for 
   var hasType = (type) => (el) => el.type === type;